# Why include methods in a public API like Thread.destroy() that aren't implemented?

Tags: java, api-design

I'm a bit puzzled by this one. There are some methods in the Java API like `Thread.destroy()` that aren't implemented at all. (I know it hasn't been implemented probably because it would be deadlock prone, but that's not what I'm getting at.) If it's not implemented, then why even include it in the public API? It's just a useless method that people could call to cause an exception at runtime.

I can see the point in this sort of thing when you're implementing an interface and a particular implementation doesn't implement all the methods for one reason or another. But that isn't the case with thread.

The only thing I can think of is that it was a design decision taken by Java devs in the early days to show what features planned to be in place - and obviously with the discoveries of the thread issues it never paid off. But that's a wild guess and it seems a bit of a silly one.

Can anyone else shed some light on this one?

Following on from this, since it's not implemented why don't they remove it? I know there's the whole thing with Java backwards compatibility, but since there's no code that could possibly call this method and ever work at runtime, surely it's not a code-breaking change? Or does the fact it could compile before and can't now count (even though it couldn't compile to anything meaningful?)

**Edit: As of Java 11, it is indeed removed.**

Comment: "The only thing I can think of is that it was a design decision taken by Java devs in the early days to show what features planned to be in place - and obviously with the discoveries of the thread issues it never paid off. But that's a wild guess and it seems a bit of a silly one." -- this is probably the case.

Comment: Sure would removing it break backcomp. If you go from "valid java program" to "fails with link errors" that's clearly a regression ;) While that case is quite strange (I agree with your assumption about what happened), there are enough backcomp hacks that lead to functions being called that do absolutely nothing (ask the windows devs ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [Thread.destroy()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#destroy%28%29) links to [reasons for deprecation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) of Thread's methods. Curiously, the link states:

> We are not implementing it at this time, but neither are we
>   deprecating it

even though method is clearly annotated as deprecated.  It is as if they included it in the API, so people could call it and expect the *designed* functionality to work later, then thought better of it, so they included the note saying "Not implemented, but not deprecated", then just went ahead and deprecated it, and forgot to update the documentation.

Oracle does take [bug reports](http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/index.jsp), perhaps this qualifies for feedback they could use to enhance their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#destroy%28%29) for it?

> This method was originally designed to destroy this thread without any
>   cleanup. Any monitors it held would have remained locked. However, the
>   method was never implemented. If if were to be implemented, it would
>   be deadlock-prone in much the manner of suspend(). If the target
>   thread held a lock protecting a critical system resource when it was
>   destroyed, no thread could ever access this resource again. If another
>   thread ever attempted to lock this resource, deadlock would result.
>   Such deadlocks typically manifest themselves as "frozen" processes.
>   For more information, see Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and
>   Thread.resume Deprecated?.

Also, from ["Java Thread Primitive Deprecation"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) (linked from above):

> Thread.destroy has never been implemented. If it were implemented, it
>   would be deadlock-prone in the manner of Thread.suspend. (In fact, it
>   is roughly equivalent to Thread.suspend without the possibility of a
>   subsequent Thread.resume.) We are not implementing it at this time,
>   but neither are we deprecating it (forestalling its implementation in
>   future). While it would certainly be deadlock prone, it has been
>   argued that there may be circumstances where a program is willing to
>   risk a deadlock rather than exit outright.

Comment: The question isn't why it wasn't implemented, but why it was included in the API and THEN not implemented, which is quite a strange behavior. It's not that common (ie never heard of it at all apart from this) to design an API and never implement parts of it at all. My memory about ancient java is a bit fuzzy, but I assume they designed the APIs first, then implemented the most important stuff and released it, planning to implement the rest with the next release and later decided for the stated reasons to leave it at that.

Comment: Never heard of it? What about java.util.Collection, where six of the methods specify that they might throw UnsupportedOperationException, or java.util.List, where ten of them do? Have you ever implemented an interface like MessageConverter, which has a toMessage() and a fromMessage(), but only written one of them because you don't care about the other way? I can't speak to the historical decisions beyond what I wrote in my answer, but they sound like exactly this pattern: API is designed to account for expected scenarios, implementation is written appropriately.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart In the above examples the methods either *might* throw UnsupportedOperationException or they do through conforming to an interface (which I specified as known behaviour in the question.) This is different, and the docs really don't answer that question!